# One-Liner: Line -> Node -> Line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to draw this diagram, with just a single line of TikZ?

[image]

This was drawn with

```
\node (A) [draw] {$h(t)$};
\draw (A.west) +(-1,0) circle (2pt) node [left] {$x(t)$} -- (A);
\draw (A.east) -- +(1,0) circle (2pt) node [right] {$y(t)=h(t)*x(t)$};
```

However, I'm looking for a way to optimize it with a single line (the current code is quite redundant). HEre's my attempt

```
\draw (0,0) circle (2pt) node [left] {$x(t)$} -- ++(1,0) node [draw,right] {$h(t)$} -- +(1,0) circle (2pt) node [right] {$y(t)=h(t)*x(t)$};
```

which creates this:

[image]

Obviously, it doesn't work, since the path just proceeds from the (A.west) and strikes the box.

Comment: `\draw(1,0)node(A){A}(0,0)--(A)--(2,0);`

Comment: @Symbol1 thanks, that's an obvious solution, essentially putting two lines into one (i.e. defining the node and drawing lines to and from this node) (but via more or less absolute positioning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options demonstrated below, both generate this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% first option
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[left] {$x(t)$} circle[radius=2pt] -- node[draw,fill=white]{$h(t)$} (3,0) circle[radius=2pt] node[right] {$y(t) = h(t) \ast x(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
% second option
\begin{tikzpicture} % four lines just to easier see what happens, you can write it in one
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt] -- (3,0) circle[radius=2pt]
   node[pos=0,left] {$x(t)$} 
   node[midway,draw,fill=white]{$h(t)$} 
   node[pos=1,right] {$y(t) = h(t) * x(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And a slightly different approach:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node (a) [draw] {$h(t)$} (a.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$x(t)$} circle[radius=2pt] (a.east) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {$y(t)=h(t)*x(t)$} circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The trick is actually [fill=white], as I see it. Neat :-)

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I added another approach as well.